# Why does my flash[:notice] appear permanently on the redirected page? - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Why does my flash[:notice] appear permanently on the redirected page? - Rails 3.1

In my `ApplicationController` I have this `before_filter`:

```
before_filter   :expire_session

def expire_session
  if session
    reset_session if session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago
    flash[:error] = "Your session has timed out. Please log back in."
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  end
end
```

In my `sessions_controller`, these are the `error` and `destroy` actions:

```
  def error
    flash[:error] = "We're sorry. You need to sign in to get access to that page."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end
```

It works perfectly, i.e. it expires my session after `X` minutes of inactivity - which is what I want. The issue is, when it redirects me to the `root_path`, it has this message:

```
Your session has timed out. Please log back in.
```

If I reload the page, the message is still there. If I close the tab and come back to that URL, that message is still there.

The other messages generated in `flash[:notice] or flash[:error]` display only once and when you reload the page, they are gone.

Why is this one sticking around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite expire method:

```
before_filter   :expire_session

def expire_session
  if session && session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago
    reset_session
    flash[:error] = "Your session has timed out. Please log back in."
  elsif session
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this error for your answer too: `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass`. I am not logged in, and it gives me this error...which doesn't make sense, given that you check if `session` even exists.

Comment: Try to update first and second conditions to this: 

    if session && session[:last_seen] && session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago
      # ...
    elsif session && session[:last_seen]
      # ...

Comment: Actually, one issue now is that the `flash[:error]` message is not displayed at all. It times out and redirects to the right path, but there is no flash[:error] message. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I had to change to a `flash[:notice]`. Now we are all squared away.

Answer (score 1):

You are not splitting on the condition, so you are setting the flash every request. You can fix it like this:

```
def expire_session
  return unless session

  if session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago
    session[:last_seen] = Time.now
  else
    reset_session
    flash[:error] = "Your session has timed out. Please log back in."
  end
end
```

Comment: I keep getting this error: `undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass` I guess I get that because I am logged out. But even if I modify the `if` statement to be `if session && session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago` it still gives me the same thing.

Comment: The problem is you must have never set session[:last_seen] in the first place. If you want to use this system for session timeout mangagment, then whenever someone logs in (or whenever you start a session), you have to set `session[:last_seen] = Time.now`. Otherwise session[:last_seen] is just nil when it gets to the expire_session callback.

Comment: That didn't work, but Sergey's answer did. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @marcamillion, I was actually originally going to post Sergey's exact suggestion, but I decided to opt for my suggestion instead because I think his will fail in a certain edge condition.

Comment: @marcamillion, In any case, isn't his answer simply wrong? He has it so that if the session is under 15 minutes (`if session && session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago`) it expires. Otherwise it keeps it valid? Seems like his logic us just backwards. I also answered several minutes before him, and got the logic right. Seems incorrect to give him the checkmark.

Comment: Also, I realize I wasn't going to suggest the conditions he suggested, but something similar. The conditions he suggested will just make expire_session never do anything. `session[:last_seen]` is `nil` so if you added the conditions he recommended, both is `if` and his `elsif` will fail, leading the method to do nothing at all.

Comment: So his answer is broken in two different ways. It only "works" in the sense that it doesn't give an error. But it also doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Anyway, the suggestion I was going to make in my code is to change `if session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago` to `if !session[:last_seen] || session[:last_seen] < 15.minutes.ago`. The edge condition I was worried about is not a real problem, it's an extreme edge condition and not worth worrying about.